# Combining A-frame with Three.js

Tags: three.js, aframe

I was wondering...

Is it possible to add Three.js elements to a A-frame scene?
Assuming A-frame is built upon Three.js, and

```
three Version: ^0.74.0
```

is logged into your console it shouldn't be a weird thing right?

I tried this code onto my A-frame scene element:

```
let scene = document.getElementsByTagName('a-scene');
console.log(scene);

var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {  } );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 10, 10 ), sphereMaterial );
    sphere.position.set(150, 20, -170);
    scene.add( sphere );
```

But it doesnt work because the scene object doesnt have a add function.. Maybe because the A-frame scene is not an instance of a normal WebGLRenderer?

Does anybody have experience with this? It would be very awesome!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A-Frame is built on top of three.js and exposes all underlying functionality.

`<a-scene>`.object3D gives you access to the `THREE.Scene`.

Each `<a-entity>` has an `object3D` that is a group. You use `getObject3D(name)` and `getOrCreateObject3D(name, constructor` to add things to the group.

To add three.js elements within the A-Frame framework, use the Entity-Component system that A-Frame provides.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('mythreejsthing', {
  schema: {
    // ... Define schema to pass properties from DOM to this component
  },

  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;  // Entity.
    var mythreejsobject = // ... Create three.js object.
    el.setObject3D('mesh', mythreejsobject);
  }
});
```

https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/entity.html#object3d
https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/component.html

Comment: Can you give me an example of what goes inside the schema brackets? I tried this and I don't see my Three.JS object

Comment: This would be a minimal example, then, based on Kevins answer.
http://codepen.io/dirkk0/pen/YpNrQR

Comment: I'm working on a project on [8th Wall](https://www.8thwall.com/) using A-Frame and Three.js. I'm using a component called ["text-geometry"](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/text-geometry) which generates extruded text. It keeps giving me an error `getOrCreateObject3D has been deprecated. Use setObject3D() and object3dset event instead.` for the line `mesh = el.getOrCreateObject3D('mesh', THREE.Mesh)` ... how would I do that?